# Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 to SQL Server 2014 Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, upgrade

I am upgrading from `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2` to `SQL Server 2014` and receiving an error I cannot get past. Everything checks out before the upgrade runs.

The upgrade stops at `SqlEngineConfigAction_upgrade_validation_Cpu64` with an error that says :

> No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the account name, that is, the login name or user name. Windows creates security ID for each account we create. It could be the case where security ID is missing for some account. You may try creating a new username as suggested in the following referenced article.

http://community.norton.com/en/forums/solution-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-was-done-error

Hope this helps.